# Setup custom IQ Implementation to read the following XMPP.

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I want to read and process the following custom IQ Packet. Any one know where I can find a good example?

```
<iq from='pubsub.xmpp.exmaple.net' to='town@xmpp.exmaple.net/Smack' type='result' id='publish-drop-at-4f21a00ce4b0bea7ce62e026'>
        <query xmlns='exmaple:pubsub'>
            <drop>
                <id type='id'>4f49c82ce4b05dc1f0fb9ebb</id>
                <lastEditorId type='id'>marcus</lastEditorId>
                <creatorId type='id'>8732</creatorId>
                <lastEditDate type='date'>1330235436550</lastEditDate>
                <version type='integer'>0</version>
                <creator type='map'>
                    <alias type='string'>marcus</alias>
                </creator>
                <creationDate type='date'>1330235436550</creationDate>
                <path type='path'>town</path>
                <elems type='map'>
                    <song_name type='string'>qewrqwe</song_name>
                    <artist type='string'>wrqer</artist>
                </elems>
    >
            </drop>
        </query>
    </iq>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the documentation on [PacketListener/PacketExtensionFilter or PacketCollector](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/processing.html)

You should be able to find some examples of each in the Smack source and test code.  Here is an [example of PacketCollector](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk/source/org/jivesoftware/smack/util/SyncPacketSend.java?hb=true).

Comment: Thank you so much. http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk/test/org/jivesoftware/smack/test/SmackTestCase.java?r=11826 and a little bit of patients and I was able to get it to work.